# Jest mockResolvedValue missing axios properties

Tags: axios, jestjs

If Jest's `mockResolvedValue` return type is `AxiosResponse`, why are most of properties you'd expect in a `AxiosResponse` missing?

### Example:

1. create a spy to spy on some API

`const spy = jest.spyOn(someAPI, "makeRequest")`

Then set up a mock response..

`spy.mockResolvedValue({ data: successRes })`

The return type of `mockResolvedValue` is...
`jest.SpyInstance<Promise<AxiosResponse<unknown>>`.

Yes the following Typescript error occurs:

```
...is missing the following properties from type 'AxiosResponse<unknown>': status, statusText, headers, config
```